# Travel by my car or travel with my car?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct form of this question ?

I travel by my car Vs I travel with my car ? 
Is it correct to say I drive to office in my car ?

Comment: Travel *by* car, travel in *my* car (a little awkward) and yes, you can drive to the office in your car. Please see our [sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for further questions of this nature.

Answer (score 5):

You can:

- Travel by car
- Travel in your car

But you wouldn't:

- Travel with your car (Unless you're traveling with your car as a possession instead of using it as a mode of transportation.)

Though these are small sentences, there are a few rules governing their structure. [Here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/verbs)'s a link to a primer.